# Persistent sync (rsync) of local files to GCS bucket

Tags: synchronization, google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil

I found out how to easily sync a local folder to my bucket at GCS.

Like `gsutil -m rsync -r -d . gs://mybucket/`

I want to have a "persistent" sync going on, so that whenever any local files change, they will be synced with the bucket. I haven't found any way to do this with gsutil. Is there, or is there any other approach? (Like coding a local app using json API etc). BTW, I would need to sync in realtime (or close to realtime), not with cron jobs like every 10th minute.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'm using this script for now:

```
while true
do
    gsutil -m rsync -r -d /mylocal/folder/ gs://mybucket/
sleep 1
done
```